# Get the following error when trying to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Just shifted from rails 3.0.0 to 3.1.0

When I try to run `rails s`, I get the following error:

```
`alias_method': undefined method `method_missing_with_paginate' for class `ActiveSupport::Deprecation::DeprecatedConstantProxy' (NameError)
```

Comment: any one??? im a newbie to ror

Answer (score 0):

Probably a problem with your pagination gem or plugin. Do you use `will_paginate` or `Kaminari` ? Try to update your pagination gem to the latest version. A few weeks ago [Mislav](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/) has published the new [version 3.0 of will_paginate](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2011/08/will_paginate-3.0/), which works with Rails 3. Kaminari also works with Rails 3.

Comment: I use will_paginate. Will try to update the gem to the latest version and keep you posted...

Answer (score 0):

The error concerns **with**_paginate. Are you sure you didn't simply misspell `will_paginate` somewhere?